# Creating Multiple dataframes in a loop from function result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I have a function that calls an API and retrieves data. The input of this function is a Year.

**Objective:** I have a list of years and want to call the function sequentially in a loop, and add the results to either:

1. multiple Dataframes (changing the names as it loops)
2. or append to a single Dataframe as new dimensions.

**Issue:** For multiple dataframes, I am trying to run a loop, where each iteration creates a new dataframe, and names it based on the year:

```
for b_years in base_years:
    if b_years != '' and b_years >= 2017:
        output_df_ + b_years = pd.DataFrame(getAPICore(b_years))
```

**Obs.** base_years is a DF with the unique list of years.

**Error:** For the above snippet, the first part of the third line gives an operator assignment error.

**Question 1:** How can this operation be performed?

**Question 2:** If instead of multiple dataframes, I appended every new function result as a new dimension of a single dataframe:

```
for b_years in base_years:
    if b_years != '' and b_years >= 2017:
        outputdf_name = pd.DataFrame.append(getAPICore(b_years))
```

the function ends with no error/result. Is there a way to do this operation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Generally, if you find yourself wanting to create a group of variable names that only differ by the numbers at the end, it's a sign that a list or dict would be a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with the years and the dataframes. You can access any dataframe by the year.

```py
df_dict = dict()
for b_years in base_years:
    if b_years != '' and b_years >= 2017:
        df_dict[b_years] = pd.DataFrame(getAPICore(b_years))
```

You can create a list of dataframes, add the year as a column, and concat them:

```py
df = []
for b_years in base_years:
    if b_years != '' and b_years >= 2017:
        df_ = pd.DataFrame(getAPICore(b_years))
        df_['year'] = b_years
        df.append(df_)

df = pd.concat(df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: The first could even be done in one line if you like: `df_dict = {y: pd.DataFrame(getAPICore(y)) for y in base_years if y != '' and y >= 2017}`

Comment: Yes. I avoided dict comprehension for readibility in this example, but you are right ;)

Comment: Heh, to me the comprehension is more readable, but no harm keeping the loop, especially when that's what was in the original code!